# Getting Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen When trying to open remote file url in Roo gem(Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, roo-gem

I have stored an file in AWS s3 storage when trying to open an file to import data using **roo** gem, It raising following error `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

```
def self.import(file, user_id)
        imported_file = ImportedFile.find(file)
        spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(open(imported_file.file_url), extension: :csv)
        spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(imported_file.file)
      header = spreadsheet.row(1)//raising error here
end
```

I even tried this also

```
spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(imported_file.file_url)
```

Getting below error in log

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /uploads/imported_files/7a6f0463-b3cd-48f8-a579-bc27951242fe/13c96e3e-d3f3-4ed8-8d9a-b9ea03c0cc8c.csv
```

Comment: Doesn‘t look like a full URL

Comment: @neuhaus, I tried with full url followed by https, header = spreadsheet.row(1), Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory rb_sysopen - /uploads/imported_files/7a6f0463-b3cd-48f8-a579-bc27951242fe/13c96e3e-d3f3-4ed8-8d9a-b9ea03c0cc8c.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally following code is worked for me.

```
spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(open(imported_file.file_url), extension: File.extname(imported_file.file_url).gsub('.','').to_sym) rescue nil
```

Comment: I don't recommend hiding all the exceptions with `rescue nil` since it can shadow a lot of issues.

Comment: Did you need to require the `open-uri`?

Comment: @KARASZI István, Not required without require it was working

Answer (score 5):

To open URLs you should require the `open-uri` library first:

```
require 'open-uri'
```

See the example:

```
open('http://example.com/')
# throws Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://example.com/

require 'open-uri'
open('http://example.com/')
# opens the website
```

Comment: I accept your answer, but it is not working with  spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(open(imported_file.file_url)), throwing ArgumentError: Can't detect the type of /tmp/open-uri20171011-8816-ckswos - please use the :extension option to declare its type. but after passing extension along with this spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(open(imported_file.file_url), extension: :csv) it was working fine, but I am thinking it is not a perfect solution

Comment: I believe Roo is trying to - questionably - guess the file type by the extension and `open-uri` downloads the URL to a temporary file, that is the reason you need to set the extension.